# remove unwanted characters in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I am populating all contacts from address book. i have to send to server only phone numbers without country code & without any special characters & spaces .i.e. pure phone numbers. but my address book phone numbers are in different formats, like these

```
"+91 99-70-044099",
"*125#",
"+91 8605-681220",
"+919975806164",
9822771881,
02026697467,
"+**62*+91675#",
"+91 80-87177718",
"\U202a+91 81 49 753637\U202c",
"8308-412345",
"094-19-241898",
"*123*7#",
"+6596913434",
7898989876565657
```

for making these without special characters & spaces , I did following code

```
NSError *error;
            NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber
                                                                       error:&error];
            NSUInteger phoneValidates = [detector numberOfMatchesInString:phoneNumber
                                                                  options:0
                                                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [phoneNumber length])];
          //  NSLog(@"res=%d",phoneValidates);

            if (phoneValidates)
            {

                NSLog(@"yes it is phone number %@",phoneNumber);
                NSString *str = [phoneNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"" ];
                NSLog(@"after=%@",str);
                str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"" ];
                NSLog(@"after=%@",str);
                str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"" ];
                NSLog(@"after=%@",str);
                str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\U202a" withString:@"" ];
                NSLog(@"after=%@",str);

                str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\U202c" withString:@"" ];
                NSLog(@"after=%@",str);

                [arr_contact addObject:str];
            }
```

even going through  above code, array contains below format numbers

```
"\U202a918149753637\U202c",
```

How to remove these characters? How to get only number from this.
some numbers are with country code then how to remove country code, my problem is that 
91 is my country code but also i have some number which starts with 91 i.e. real number, not a country code. also i have to check this for all types of country code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get only numbers:

```
NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:phoneNumber.length];

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:phoneNumber];
NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];

while ([scanner isAtEnd] == NO) 
{
  NSString *buffer;
  if ([scanner scanCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:&buffer]) 
   {
      [result appendString:buffer];
   } 
   else 
   {
      [scanner setScanLocation:([scanner scanLocation] + 1)];
   }
}

NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Comment: yes, it gives only numbers. any idea about removing country code

Comment: u gotta do a seperate logic for that. there is no inbuilt functionality for that. The best way i would suggest is by having two separate nodes for phone number and country code instead of having a single node as u have now.

Answer (score 5):

```
NSString * strippedNumber =
 [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[^0-9]"
                                         withString:@""
                                            options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [mobileNumber length])];
```

Comment: that is just way too clean

Answer (score 1):

\U202a, \U202b, \U202c, \U202d are control characters. They are defined in the NSCharacterSet. So here is one way to remove the control characters from a given string ..

```
NSCharacterSet *cc = [NSCharacterSet controlCharacterSet];
NSString *cs = [[searchString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cc]
                componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Control characters belong to the Cc and Cf categories. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

I do it like so:

```
NSMutableString *strippedString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:10];
```

I end up with an empty string, but the code doesn't crash.

I had to resort to good old C instead:

```
 for (int i=0; i<[phoneNumber length]; i++) 
 {
     if (isdigit([phoneNumber characterAtIndex:i]))
     {
         [strippedString appendFormat:@"%c",[phoneNumber characterAtIndex:i]];
     }
 }
```